# How to create my own CPU pool on boot in XEN

Tags: xen

I can manually create new cpupool using xl toolstack and reassign some CPU
from one pool to another here is an example main idea is to  use different pool for dom0 and domU's:

Create a new pool:

```
$  xl cpupool-create name=\"NewPool\"
```

Remove CPU from the older pool:

```
$ xl cpupool-cpu-remove Pool-0 <1>
```

Add free CPU to new cpupool:

```
$ xl cpupool-cpu-add NewPool <1>
```

Now my `NewPool` has 1 attached CPU and `Pool-0` 3 CPU (in case 4 CPU on the machine).

The problem is on re-boot my `NewPool` is deleted and a "default pool" named `Pool-0` will be created. And all CPU's assign to it.
I want to save my `NewPool` on every reboot. I understand that I can make some service using systemd and my own script, but maybe there is native support by XEN to do it.

I read this:

https://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Cpupools_Howto

this:

https://xenbits.xen.org/docs/4.11-testing/man/xlcpupool.cfg.5.html

and default man in Xen git folder

```
docs/man/xlcpupool.cfg
```

And there is no any mention regarding cpupool which can be created on system boot. Any suggestion, please.

System settings:

- Xen 4.6
- kernel 4.1.27 for dom0.

Comment: The `CPUPOOL.cfg` reference you link suggests using that file should be possible. However, in my tests I haven't been able to use it, seems it's not read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPU pools are not persistent, they need to be configured after each reboot of the host. There is no way around a custom .service file to create them.